# How do i observe only one component when adding a breakpoint in angular?

Tags: angular, breakpoints

I am trying to change the routing based on the window size. I have it working by using a breakpoint but this is observing all pages/components of my project, rather than just the one component that I am trying to include multiple views for. How do I specify only one component to have the min-width: 900px?

```js
    <<list.component.ts>>

    import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    constructor(private bpo: BreakpointObserver, private router: Router) {}

    @Component({
      templateUrl: './list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss'],

      providers: [Service]
    })

     ngOnInit(): void {
        this.bpo.observe(['(min-width: 900px)'])
          .subscribe(result => {
            if (result.matches) {
              this.router.navigate(["/list"]);
            } else {
              this.router.navigate(["/list-expandable"]);
            }
          });

      }
```

All of my pages are switching to the list-expandable when the window size is below 900px. I only want the list window to switch when the size is below 900px. The rest should stay the same when the window shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

You must unsubscribe from the observable. Create a private variable `minWidthSubscription` and set it to subscription returned from `this.bpo.observe.subscribe(...)`. Then in `ngOnDestroy()` call `this.minWidthSubscription.unsubscribe()`.

```
private minWidthSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private bpo: BreakpointObserver, private router: Router) {}
```

Comment: I received an error :            core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ListComponent -> Subscription]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListComponent -> Subscription]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Subscription!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ListComponent -> Subscription]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListComponent -> Subscription]:

Comment: I updated the answer. You don't inject the subscription in the constructor which is why you're getting those the static injector errors.